# jsp page downloading instead of opening in browser

Tags: html, jsp

I am new to jsp programming. I was previously able to open a jsp page in the browser to view the html layouts, however now when i try to open the a jsp page, the file download window pops up and asks me to either save or open the file in IE9 and just displays the whole code in Firefox.

I have tomcat installed but it is a hassle to run it every time just to see minor modifications. Is there a way to have the jsp page open in eithe rIE9 or firefox so I can view the html aspect?
Thank you

Comment: To avoid the obvious, are you opening the page by `http://` or `file://`? If by `http://`, post the smallest representation of your webapp's `web.xml` which still reproduces the problem.

Comment: I was opening the file by directing it to the file path, so by file:// .

Comment: In my case it was because I replaced all "html" instances with "jsp" in the code. As a result `contentType="text/html;"` became  `contentType="text/jsp;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should start TomcatServer and throw your webpages (jsp) inside the webapps folder.
Try to do it, for example:

```
<%
out.println("test");
%>
```

Save your file called index.jsp.
When you call the web address, try to put this: http:\localhost:8080\yourfolder\index.jsp

Remember,
you can put html code togheter jsp code.

The answer appears stupid, but, that's it.

Regards.

Comment: I can run the webpage fine through tomcat and everthing works. I want to try to display the html portion of a single jsp on a web browser without going through tomcat. is that possible?

Comment: Let me undertand you. I think you rename the file to .html and take jsp code off. You can't open a jsp file without a server side (tomcat, jboss).

Comment: You are correct. By removing the java based code, I can view it on the browser as an html. Guess I will have to work on it with Tomcat and edit the page in the web app  folders and move any changes I like back to file in my ide. Thank You for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1):

add tomcat embed jasper dependency in your pom.xml file.
u can even copy this and paste in pom.xml

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed- 
   jasper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.40</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working on tomcat server, by default the parser of jsp pages in not present.
So, please add the following dependency in you pom.xml in your project to render jsp pages in browser

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.40</version>
</dependency>
```